# How to replace something in quotes with something that you already have in buffer?

Tags: vim

I would like to replace something in quotes with a string that I already have stored in buffer  (from yanking `y` or deleting `d`) like so:

`"something very important"`

to

`"something even more important"`

Answer (score 4):

how about

```
vi"p
```

cursor within `"`

tricky question... I first came up with `di"P`. however the `d` will reset your unnamed register (the buffer you meant in your question)......

**EDIT based on comment**

I didn't see that requirement in your question. if you want to keep the register value, you could try

```
nnoremap <leader>pi" :let t=@"<cr>vi"p:let @"=t<cr>
```

in this way, when your cursor between `"`s, just type `<leader>pi"`, value in quotes would be changed into the value of unnamed registers and the register keeps the same value.

Comment: `vi"p` was that I was looking for :) I upvote your answer but I'll leave it unaccepted for few hours if somebody can come up with different approach.

Comment: I have tried it several times already and unfortunately I can see that marking the text in visual mode and then pasting something in there will replace the buffer :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original register contents (instead of replacing them with the replaced text), you can use my [ReplaceWithRegister plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703). The command would be `gri"` then.